# Datatables jquery-ui and position of global search field

Tags: datatables

With Datatables, I just switched over from the Datatables css to the jquery.datTable.jqueryui.css.

I've been having a hard time trying to figure out how to correct these issues:

1. The property that will let me correct the label text vertical alignment of the  "show ... records per page', 
   so I can get it to v-align to the bottom
   (some other style I have must be hitting it and taking it to v-top
   and it looks bad like that).
2. How can I get the "search" label and field back up on the far right
   and on the same line as the "show ... records" field?
3. How would you apply styles to the text labels of those fields (color, size, etc.)?

I have no styles or attributes effecting things right now, other than whatever base style might be causing the "show...records" text to v-align to the top.

I've tried a few solution and the best result I've gotten so far is that search will move over to the right like it normally would be, except it's still on a new line (so one line down from the "show...records" text & field.

Thanks for any help.

[image]

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../css/jquery-ui.min.css">  
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../css/jquery-ui.structure.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../css/jquery-ui.theme.min.css">    
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../css/dataTables.jqueryui.css"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../css/jquery.dataTables_themeroller">
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the "records per page", filter, and pagination on the top of your datatable; spaced using bootstrap grid classes.

```
sDom:  '<"H"r<"col-sm-5"i><"col-sm-3"f><"col-sm-4"p>>t',
```

[image: Datatable result]

Comment: I believe the question was "*Datatables **jquery-ui** and position of global search field*" :)

Comment: @davidkonrad the question imho was how to vertically align his datatable elements. My answer provides Reno a way to do that, and a end result of what the elements will look like. Using jquery-ui doesn't prevent you from using bootstrap css classes, or custom css classes in the datatable's sDom.